# Columns of strings as a dataframe

Tags: r

R noob here.

I have two columns of information saved as such:

```
il = 'Illy'
la = 'Lavazza'
identity = c(il, il, la, il, la, la, il, la, la, il)
response = c(il, la, il, il, il, la, il, la, la, la)
```

I want to save these under a new variable called e that will be a dataframe. However I want it to treat these strings as factors and not strings. The function

```
 e = data.frame(identity, response)
```

by itself apparently does not do the trick since the output of

```
is.factor(e[1,1])
```

is false. What should I be doing?

EDIT: Nevermind guys I found the answer, you had to add as an option to data.frame(identity, response, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

Comment: Your test if flawed. Try instead testing your success with `is.factor(e[[1]])` and do now read the help page for `?Extract`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm right but I have not achieved my goal. You need to spend much more time reading `?Extract`. It is an incredibly dense but important page if you want to use R productively.

Comment: Haha ok I will. I also plan on reading the whole of the R user guide by the end of april!

Comment: @NormanB: also note that you can change the `stringsAsFactors` setting globally: either via `options("stringsAsFactors"=FALSE)`(check current setting via `options("stringsAsFactors")`; must be repeated for each new R session) or by making sure the former *set-options* statement is part of either your `Rprofile.site` or `Renviron.site` file (see help page under `?Startup`; this makes it a permanent setting)

Comment: @Rappster That's also useful, thank you!

Comment: @NormanB `stringsAsFactors` **is** the default, so this only didn't work if you *changed* the factory default or you did something you didn't tell us about.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I didn't, the only thing I can think of is I fixed the error "Sweave.sty file not found" earlier by copying this file along with Rd.sty (I think thats what it was called) and putting it in the proper tex directory. I followed this tutorial: http://joey711.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/adding-sweave-sty-and-rd-sty-to-your-latex-path-in-mac-os-x/